# JAVA11: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding$Style cannot be found

Tags: soap, binding, java-11

One of the third party JAR I am using uses this class and unable to find javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding$Style implementation.

Any help?

Comment: Try: javax.jws:jsr181-api:1.0-MR1 dependency

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @miche.atucha. Adding following dependency worked for me

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/jsr181-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-MR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 11, the package starts with javax and jaxb has been removed from Java 11 package. they are now available as a separate module.

> Note that the package name for the JAXB API has changed in Java 11
> from javax.xml.bind to jakarta.xml.bind. You will need to use the new
> package name in your code.

add below libs from jakarta

```
javax.jws:javax.jsw-api:version
javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:version
javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:version
javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:version
```